# FragmentActivity pass bundle to FragmentList specified in xml

Tags: android, android-fragments

Overview of what I need:

Pass String from `FragmentActivity` to `FragmentList`. Said `FragmentList` is specified in the xml as below:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MultiContactsFragmentList" >

...

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/multiContactsList_fragment"
    android:name="com.sf.lidgit_android.content.MultiContactsFragmentList"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
```

The problem in the code lies here (by the way, I'm using **Support Library** because I target API level 10), in my **class that extends from FragmentActivity:**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstance);
    ...
            inviteByEmail();
}

public void inviteByEmail(){        
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_multi_contacts_email_picker);
    MultiContactsFragmentList fragmentList = 
            (MultiContactsFragmentList)
             getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.multiContactsList_fragment);
    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
    extras.putString(MultiContactsFragmentList.DATA_TO_PICK, MultiContactsFragmentList.EMAIL_DATA);
    fragmentList.setArguments(extras);
}
```

Here is the thing, **fragmentList** is `null`. I figure it's because of the life cycle (I'm not aware to the `FragmetnActivity`-`FragmentList` life cycle). The FragmentList is yet to be created. Is that it? I know the other way around would be to have my **FragmentActivity** "save" the data, and have the FragmentList access it (since FragmentActivity is available to it's Fragments, I believe).

**EDIT**

My FragmentList class (the fragment I'm trying to pass a Bundle to), implements `LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>` . I don't know if that influences or not, but I tried the first answer below and got an error on my FragmentList caused by a **null pointer Exception**, it appears that the **onLoadFinished(..)** method was called before the **onCreate(..)**, because the `null Pointer Exception` happened on the **onLoadFinished(..)**, stating the `adapter` was null.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d("invite", "oncreate called");
    String[] fromColumns = {ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME, this.view_ID_Data};
    int[] toViews = {R.id.contact_name, R.id.contact_data};

    getLoaderManager().initLoader(MULTI_CONTACTS_LIST_LOADER, null, this);

    this.adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.custom_list_contacts_multiple_choice,
            null, fromColumns, toViews,
            CursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER);

    setListAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> arg0, Cursor cursor) {
    adapter.swapCursor(cursor);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your layout to this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And in your activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstance);
    ...
    inviteByEmail();
}

public void inviteByEmail(){        
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_multi_contacts_email_picker);
    MultiContactsFragmentList fragmentList = new MultiContactsFragmentList();
    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
    extras.putString(MultiContactsFragmentList.DATA_TO_PICK, MultiContactsFragmentList.EMAIL_DATA);
    fragmentList.setArguments(extras);
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.add(R.id.content, fragmentList);
    ft.commit();
}
```

The method setArguments(Bundle args) for the fragment can only be called just after creating the fragment, so if you embed you fragment in the XML the argumments setting may no be happening at all even if you call it. This way you have to attach the fragment yourself but you will have the arguments when you access it.

Comment: I don't know if this has to do with anything, but inside my FragmentList I'm using a CursorLoader. If I set upt things as you've suggested, NullPointerExceptions start jumping out everywhere , as if the onLoadFinished() were called before the onCreateView() of the FragmentList.